# Trouble adding/testing addition of an object to a ManyToMany relation in Django

Tags: django

I have the below view;

```
class MemberAdd(View): 
    def get(self, request):
        raise Http404

    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = AddMemberForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Station.objects.get(pk=pk).members.add(
                form.cleaned_data['user']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home_station",
                                        kwargs={'pk':pk},
                                        )
                                )
```

The `AddMemberForm`;

```
class AddMemberForm(Form):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
                                  empty_label='Choose a User',
    )
```

As you can see after addition to a ManyToMany relation the view redirects to a page I have as homepage for a particular model object. I have in it the objects in the ManyToMany relation listed and I indeed find the newly added object there.

But when I run the below test;

```
class TestStationManagement(TestCase):
    .
    .
    .    
    def test_add_member(self):
        """
        Tests addition of a member to station
        """
        user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='someusername',
                                        password='somepassword')
        user1.save()
        station = Station.objects.create(name='somename',
                                         address='someaddress',
                                         owner=user1)
        station.save()
        user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='someotherusername',
                                        password='someotherpassword')
        user2.save()
        self.client.post(reverse('add_member',
                                 kwargs={'pk':station.pk}),
                         {'user':user2},
                         follow=True)
        self.assertIn(user2, station.members.all())
```

I get an assertion error, `E       AssertionError: <User: someotherusername> not found in []`.

See the mistake? Please help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the user's id.

This might work :

```
add_member_post = self.client.post(reverse('add_member',
                                 kwargs={'pk':station.pk}),
                         {'user':user2.id},
                         follow=True)
```

And check if the request actually worked :

```
self.assertEqual(add_member_post.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

`station` remains the instance you created inside the test, and is not affected by anything that happens in your view. You'd need to reload it from the database:

```
self.client.post(...)
station = Station.objects.get(pk=station.pk)
self.assertIn(...)
```

Comment: Mr. Roseman that's not it. I tried reloading the station object too. `self.client.post(....) user2=User.objects.get(pk=user2.pk) station=Station.objects.get(pk=station.pk) self.assertIn(user2,station.members.all())
`

Comment: I had to send user.id instead of user. Din need to reload from db. Not user nor station. Just letting you know. Mr. Roseman thank you for the time :)